# Factorisation of numbers and squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the number $n=2^a 3^b$. How many factors of $n^2$ are less than $n$ but do not divide $n$?

I am trying to find a formula in terms of $a$ and $b$ but I can't find ways to list all the terms properly. Can someone give me some help with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello community! Thank you, i will try to ask more specifically in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to count all factors of $n^2$ less than $n,$ and then subtract the factors of $n.$

There are $\tau(n^2)=(2a+1)(2b+1)$ factors of $n^2$, and they come in distinct pairs $\{d,n^2/d\}$ except for the case $d=n.$ One of each pair is $< n.$

So the total number of divisors of $n^2$ less than $n$ is $\frac{\tau(n^2)-1}2=2ab+a+b.$

Of those, $\tau(n)-1=ab+a+b$ are divisors of $n$ less than $n.$

So you get $\frac{\tau(n^2)-1}{2}-(\tau(n)-1)=ab.$

Comment: wow!!! you are so smart